# How to save what users write in SwiftUI app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to add the ability to save what the users write, so if they go back to the homepage or close the app and re-open it, what they wrote would still be there.

[image: Let's say I wanted these names to stay on the app when I close the app and re-open it.]

Here the code I'm working with. I'm wondering if I have to add something more to it?

```
struct LandingView: View {
    @State private var oldLandingName: String = ""
    @State private var newLandingName: String = ""
    @State private var isAddingLanding = false
    @State private var landings: [String] = []
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.7)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.60))
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.3)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue.opacity(0.50))
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Add Your Travels")
                            .bold()
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            isAddingLanding = true
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    List(landings, id: \.self) { landing in
                        Text(landing).bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                            .listRowSeparatorTint(.blue)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.isEditing = true
                                self.oldLandingName = landing
                                self.newLandingName = landing
                            }
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landings!"))
            
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isAddingLanding, onDismiss: {}) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Where did you go? \(newLandingName)", text: $newLandingName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                    Button("Add") {
                        if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                            landings.append(newLandingName)
                            newLandingName = ""
                        }
                        isAddingLanding = false
                    }
                    Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isEditing, onDismiss: {}) {
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $newLandingName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                    Button("Update") {
                        if !newLandingName.isEmpty {
                            if let idx = landings.firstIndex(where: { $0 == $oldLandingName.wrappedValue }) {
                                self.landings[idx] = newLandingName
                            }
                        }
                        isEditing = false
                    }
                    Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save it to `UserDefaults`, is info is "light" and not sensitive?

Comment: Yes, it's light. just the names of places where you travel to. Example "paris", "Germany", "canada", like this pretty much

Comment: You need to edit your question and clearly explain how much data you expect to work with and its complexity. The two answers you have so far are vast overkill if all you have is a small list of short strings. So to get useful answers you need to provide more details about your needs and expectations.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, here are some common ones:

**User Defaults**: User Defaults is a simple and lightweight option for storing small amounts of data, such as user preferences or settings. It uses the UserDefaults class to store data in key-value pairs.

**JSON**: You can save data directly to the file system using APIs provided by Foundation framework. This includes reading and writing files in various formats such as text files, JSON, or custom binary formats.

**Core Data**: Core Data is a framework provided by Apple for managing the object graph and persisting data in a SQLite database or other formats. It provides an object-oriented approach and supports advanced features like data validation and relationship management.

**SQLite**: SQLite is a C library that provides a lightweight and embedded relational database. You can use SQLite directly in Swift applications to create and manage a local database file for storing structured data.

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to do that.

One effective way is to use Core Data and save your information in a way that your entities can easily grow and you don't lose consistency. Get to know more about [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata).

If you only want to save small pieces of information that are not sensitive information then you can use:

```
@AppStorage("propertyName") private var cityName = ""
```

**but I wouldn't recommend it for production.**

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways data persistence can be achieved for iOS. Two of the most popular options include Core Data, which Apple created, and Realm Swift, currently owned by MongoDB.

## Core Data

Advantages:

- Created by Apple
- Supports complex data structures
- Easier integration with CloudKit

Disadvantage:

- More setup required
- Can be complex

Here's a getting-started guide for Core Data:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-configure-core-data-to-work-with-swiftui

## Realm Swift

Advantages:

- Easier to use
- Claim to be faster

Disadvantages:

- Not developed by Apple, so new OS features might take longer to gain support

Here's a getting-started guide for Realm Swift:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Core Data to save. But I encountered another problem, which is adding a navigation bar to the current list. After clicking to enter, I can write data and save it. I found that when I write, they will appear in all the list cells, which is very bad! I hope they are independent. If you can crack it, please let me know, thank you!